# Is Circle of Protection's reflection effect based on luck?

Tags: the-binding-of-isaac-rebirth, the-binding-of-isaac-afterbirth

Every source I've found says that the [Circle of Protection](https://bindingofisaacrebirth.gamepedia.com/Circle_of_Protection) gives "a chance" to reflect the bullets it touches. Is that a flat chance or is it luck-based? If it's the latter, what's the amount of luck required to get a 100% reflection chance?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After some research and looking into the specifics of the circle of protection a bit, it seems like the reflection isn't actually luck based. According to the [Circle of Protection entry](https://bindingofisaacrebirth.gamepedia.com/Circle_of_Protection) in the BOIR Wiki, the item:

> Surrounds Isaac with a large white halo around him that pulsates.
>
> - With each pulse, the halo deals contact damage to enemies equal to Isaac's damage.
> - **Each pulse converts any enemy shots touching the ring into friendly purple homing tears that have Isaac's damage and no other tear modifiers.**

This can be seen if you check out the [video of the item in use](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=iTAksu-4MTM) on the wiki page. When an enemy tear enters the ring just as it is getting brighter it gets reflected, otherwise it passes through as normal.